# Android ViewModel instantiate twice using hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, dagger-hilt

I have a parent fragment which fetches a list from API using ViewModel and Retrofit, the ViewModel is injected with Hilt.
After the list gets fetched the parent fragment will pass to its child fragment that is inside of parent fragment.
but the problem is that ViewModel is instantiated one more time in the child fragment.

Parent Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ParentFragment : Fragment() {

    override val mViewModel: URLViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mViewBinding = getViewBinding(inflater, container)

        mViewModel.liveData.observe(this, { data ->
            {
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {

                    replace(
                        mViewBinding.fragmentContainer.id,
                        ChildFragment(data)
                    )
                }

                commit()
            } })


        mViewModel.getURL("TEST", "2021-06-18", "2021-07-18", 1 , 0 , -1, false)

    return mViewBinding.root
}

}
```

ChildFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChildFragment(val data: List<Item>) : Fragment() {

    override val mViewModel: URLViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mViewBinding = getViewBinding(inflater, container)

        // mViewModel is instantiated again and some all strings properties of it is null.


        return mViewBinding.root
    }

}
```

URLViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class URLViewModel @Inject constructor(private val urlApi: URLApi): ViewModel() {

    private val _urlLiveData = MutableLiveData<State<Any?>>()

    val urlLiveData: LiveData<State<Any?>> = _urlLiveData


    var urlName: String? = null

    var beginDate: String? = null

    var endDate: String? = null

    var adultCount = 0

    var childrenCount = 0

    var airportId = 0

    var isRoundTrip = false



    init {
        Log.e("URLViewModel", "iniialed again" )

    }

    @ExperimentalStdlibApi
    fun getUrl(urlName: String, beginDate: String, endDate: String, adultCount: Int, childCount: Int, airportId: Int, isRoundTrip: Boolean){

        Log.e("XXXXXX", "getUrl: called with url of " + urlName )


        this.urlName = urlName

        this.beginDate = beginDate

        this.endDate = endDate

        this.adultCount = adultCount

        this.childrenCount = childCount

        this.airportId = airportId

        this.isRoundTrip = isRoundTrip

        val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<State<Any?>>()

        mutableLiveData.value = State.loading()

        viewModelScope.launch {

            val res = urlApi.getURL(urlName,beginDate,endDate,adultCount,childCount,airportId,isRoundTrip)

            Log.e("URLVIewModel", "getUrl: response received" )
            _urlLiveData.value = res

        }
    }
}
```

when I wanna access some properties like beginDate, they are null, because the ViewModel is instantiated again,

Answer (score 2):

`viewModels()` delegation create view model against the same instance i.e Fragment's instance in your case. What you need to do is to create a shared View model .
There is helper delegate available for it with ktx libraries.

add the ktx dependency which you already have i guess from [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment).

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4"
```

And create view model with

```
private val viewModel by activityViewModels<UrlViewModel>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use activity shared view model. Simply request view model from parent fragment in `ChildFragment`.

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<UrlViewModel>(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use share viewmodel. Try to following code for reference.

```
  @AndroidEntryPoint
 class ParentFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: URLViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(URLViewModel::class.java)
}

}


@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChildFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: URLViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(URLViewModel::class.java)
}

}
```